# Excel Mail Merge into Word where there are multiple entries per PO Number

Tags: excel, datatable, ms-word, mailmerge, group

We have a client that requires a table on the Invoice that contains 9 columns that our software is [Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFuMw.png) unable to achieve.  I am looking at using Mail Merge to achieve this but am having issues where there are multiple row items for a client. A Purchase Order can have up to 3 line items.  Single entries are fine but I can't get the second row (where the PO has multiple items) on the one document.  I have used Power Query to get the table in proper data format and added in a helper column so that each new client has a "1".
The first invoice should have 2 line items $650 + $200 = $850.  [Mail Merge Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW0w2.png)

I have no VBA or programming experience and need this to work using Excel and Word.

Have viewed videos on UTube and replicated the Merge ok so I know it can be done but just won't work for me!

Comment: Using Excel (or even Power Query, don't know much about it) can you easily create an Excel table that has, say 28 columns, and 2 more rows than you have data rows, where
 - column 1 has the row count for the 1st row for the client, or 0 otherwise
 - columns 11 to 19 have a formula that references columns 2 to 10 in the next row
 - columns 20 to 28 have a formula that references columns 2 to 10 in the row after that
 
Then I think you could make a Word MailMerge Main document that would produce the output you need. Not what I would do, but my best guess given your starting points.

Comment: I agree that having all entries in one row would make the MailMerge flow easily.  I have used Power Query to produce the table as it involves merging several other tables.  However, I don't know how to make rows that have the same PO then move to become new columns. (A bit beyond my skills) Also this method goes against a proper data set so I've not had any luck in finding help to do this either. The Mail Merge is just not reading the ID2.  I have spent so many hours on this its crazy!

Comment: One problem is that your first line of field coding has { NEXTIF { MERGEFIELD Helper = 1 } } when it should be  { NEXTIF { MERGEFIELD Helper } = 1 } . But IMO you need to be able to tell that you have reached the end of the current PO's rows and so that you do not move to the next record in that case. AFAICS you can only do that if the first row for the PO contains a record count or the *final* record for the PO is specially marked, rather than the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Graham Mayor has a free 'Many-to-One' tool to do this type of merge. See details [here](http://www.gmayor.com/ManyToOne.htm).

I have a paid 'Visual CUT' tool that can also do this. See [video demo](https://youtu.be/tH3Mt9V9k_0).